# In Google data studio I have the following Data, How to make a easy counts?

Tags: looker-studio

Let's say I have this data, how can I segment in Google Data Studio to return the result as in next table:

| Item Name | Category | Returned |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | Fruits | 0 |
| Potato | Vegetables | 1 |
| TV | Electronics | 2 |
| Banana | Fruits | 2 |
| Tomato | Vegetables | 0 |
| Fridge | Electronics | 2 |
| Grapes | Fruits | 1 |
| Onion | Vegetables | 2 |
| AC | Electronics | 2 |
| Pineapple | Fruits | 0 |
| Carrot | Vegetables | 1 |
| Oven | Electronics | 1 |

I am looking for that end result appears like that Returned (0-2) is the count not the sum.

| Category | Returned (0) | Returned (1) | Returned (2) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fruits | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| Vegetables | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| Electronics | 0 | 1 | 2 |

I tried filtering but not appearing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

create a new calculated field with the formula:

```
CONCAT("Returned(",Returned,")")
```

Next create a PIVOT table chart with *Category* as row-dimension & above created *calculated field* as column-dimension

-

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much :) and let's say we have a lot of data for returned item, and we have to set the pivot table with returned range 0 then returned range (1-10) and returned range (11-20) how we can do?

Comment: you can try something akin to this using CASE(): https://i.imgur.com/Ur56KxB.png

Comment: My Pivot table is not returning with multiple column as of yours

Comment: please share a sample editable dash if possible for us to check out.

Comment: data is of company and due to privacy I could not share but I dont find record count metric in real data and when I make myself the count value i get this error: Re-aggregating metrics is not supported.

Comment: In the metric field you can replace 'record count' with the added calculated field (CONCAT in my case) with aggregate set to COUNT.